# im trying to check if my string contains certain words what is wrong? PYTHON

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, operand

I'm using Python to try and check if a string contains certain words. It can contain all or some of the words.

```
listCall = ('Azura', 'Fly', 'yellow')
readME = 'the color is yellow'
if listCall in readME:
    print 'we found certain words'
else:
    print 'all good'
```

Comment: sorry messed up on putting the code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K2CvQ4HQ

Comment: thats the link leading to the code

Answer (score 2):

You are testing if the *whole list `listCall* is in`readME`. You need to test for *individual words* instead:

```
if any(word in readME for word in listCall):
```

This uses a generator expression and the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to efficiently test individual words in `listCall` against the `readME` string.

Comment: Thank you! it helps me out more then you think seriously.